# What is this snowflake?

Tags: clicker-heroes

While playing, I noticed this snowflake sitting on the ground.  I'm not sure if a monster dropped it or not, but it did not get auto-picked up as gold does.

[image: Snowflake]

After clicking it, all I got was a message that says "Yay!!"

[image: Yay!!]

I've also seen a sweater that behaved the same way.  Are they the same thing?  Are there others?  Do they do anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those randomly appearing objects on the ground can be clicked for a burst of money. These are the holiday versions of the pumpkin pie and sub sandwich that will show up. You can also look out for a blue sweater which is another clickable and, an ice cube.

Some items give more money than others, but I don't remember offhand what holiday versions were worth more.

Here is an example of how much coin a single ice cube drops:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: I've not played in too long so I'm not sure what the pumpkin pie or sub sandwich are either.

Comment: In that case, all the clickable items mentioned above are money boosts. You'll also see a wrapped present (a bird during non-holiday) that scrolls across the top of the screen from time-to-time that you can click a few dozen times to activate. This will give you a random ability use (Like golden clicks, clickstorm, etc.). =)

Comment: Just a little adding, but they can also now give rubies for buying upgrades.